# A question on complex line integrals

Tags: complex-analysis

The problem was as  following
Show that

$|\int_{|z+1|=2} \frac{e^z}{z-2} dz| $ $\le$ $2\pi e$

I used that integral $\le |\frac{e^z}{z-2}|*4\pi$ where z is on the circle of radius 2 and -1 as center
 But then 
$|\frac{e^z}{z-2}|$=$ \frac{|e^z|}{|z-2|}$ and in that circle I got $|e^z| \le e $ and $|z-2| \ge 1 $ so the right hand side was $4\pi e $ instead of the required answer.

I cant find any mistake please show any if there is or any hint

Comment: Do you know, say, the Cauchy integral formula?

Comment: No we still didn't learn the  Cauchy integral theorem yet

Comment: Your bounds seem correct. But its hard to tell how to estimate the integral better without knowing what you have studied so far.

Comment: Your integrand is holomorphic inside the integration path and on a neighbourhood of it such that the pole in $z=2$ is avoided. Thus the integral vanishes.